# Cannot sign in to aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl

I'm having problems getting to the [signin page of aws](https://signin.aws.amazon.com) in Ubuntu 20.04 with latest updates. As I suspect this to be a network problem, I've tried accessing with `curl` and `openssl`. Sometimes (randomly) following commands doesn't fail and I get successful responses, but most of the time I'm getting following responses:

```
~ curl -vvv https://signin.aws.amazon.com
*   Trying 176.32.98.146:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to signin.aws.amazon.com (176.32.98.146) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to signin.aws.amazon.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to signin.aws.amazon.com:443
```

```
openssl s_client -connect signin.aws.amazon.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 313 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Some observations:

- `signing.aws.amazon.com` resolves to different ip addresses and I've checked I'm getting both successful and error responses from same ip addresses.
- When I get a successful response, usually next few calls are also successful if I keep trying.
- If I connect to a VPN, these calls never fail
- I have two ubuntu machines at home both of the have the same problem. I've installed `curl` to a windows machine and it never had the problem.
- Successful sessions are using TLSv1.2 as expected
- I have a very stable 100 Mbit connection with very low ping times and this problem doesn't happen with any other domain
- Both commands fail after 23 seconds. However when they're successful, it takes ~400ms.
- I tried to replace my router, but got the same results.
- My ISP changed my IP address, but that didn't help. As the calls are sometimes working I don't think it's a *black-listing* problem.
- I cannot connect to site with browsers or other cli tools neither.

What else can I try to find the cause of this issue?

Comment: What country are you in? Who is your ISP?

Comment: I'm in Austria and provider is teletronic